# How to make a petapoco class with a name different than table name?

Tags: c#, petapoco

I have a petapoco class with a name that is equal to the table name.

i want to change the class name without changing the table name on the DB (for upgrade reasons in my application) - how can i do it?

Comment: The first result I got with "set petapoco table name" was [this](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) which is a tutorial to that library and answers this question and many others. I have my doubts whether such minor Q&A's are particularly interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add the following:

```
...
[TableName("YourOldName")]
public class YourNewClassName
{
    ...
}
```